# silverlight datagrid styling - mystery line atop first row

Tags: silverlight-5.0

Trying to get rid of the line that appears on top of the first row of data.  I've changed about everything I can see in the DataGridStyle, DataGridHeaderStyle and DataGridRowStyle templates.  I've changed colors of various elements in case the color used to draw that line was borrowed from other grid attributes (like SeparaterBrush e.g.).  Still it remains.  Any ideas?

I don't have enough rep points to post images, but here is a link to photobucket...

http://i810.photobucket.com/albums/zz23/kpgraci/grid_zps5353246d.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In the DataGrid style template there is a rectangle named 'ColumnHeadersAndRowsSeparator'.  This is responsible for the thin gray line below the column header and above the first row.  Note that even is HeadersVisibility='None' this line still displays.

Changing this rectangle's Fill from #FFC9CACA to Transparent in the DataGrid template removes the line.